# update a tk.Label automatically like in Angular?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

How to **update** a `Label` automatically, based on a variable of another module. Is there any "Angular-like" pattern?

The following isn't working and more meant as pseudocode.

**main.py**

```
import myStatusStoreModule

# The label should update when points changes
Label(self, textvariable=myStatusStoreModule.points)
```

**myStatusStoreModule.py**

```
points = 0

def addPoints(p):
    global points
    points += p

# here could be a event listener that modifies points as well
```

Any idea?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`textvariable` will update automatically **if** the variable you give it is a tkinter Variable.

```
import Tkinter as tk

points = tk.IntVar()

def addPoints(p):
    global points
    points.set(points.get() + p)
```

You will be better off to ask questions like this in a more beginner oriented forum like learnpython.reddit.com

Comment: Thanks for your reply and suggestion. I'm getting the following error now:
`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_root'
Exception AttributeError: "IntVar instance has no attribute '_tk'" in <bound method IntVar.__del__ of <Tkinter.IntVar instance at 0x7fee4a637c68>> ignored`

Comment: That error means you made the IntVar before you made the `Tk()` instance. You need to arrange your code so that the `Tk()` is called first.

Comment: I'm creating `root = Tk()` in the main file. The `Label` is in a `class`, which listens to the `IntVar` in another module. If I create more `Tk()` instances, it works for the first time but then I get `RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop`.

Comment: Right, so you need to create root *and then* import the other file.

Comment: Your example doesn't show creating `Tk` first. This answer would be better if you explained that in the body of the question.